# Wordpress: How can I add terms to a custom taxonomy?

Tags: php, wordpress, foreach, custom-taxonomy

```
$terms = array('Audio','CD','Download','DVD','Publication','Website');
foreach( $terms as $term ) {
   //intert the term
   wp_insert_term(
        $term, // the term 
        'media-type' // the taxonomy
    );
}
```

If it is possible I would also like these terms to be the only terms and prevent the user from adding more.

Thanks.

Comment: What's wrong with your above code?

Answer (score 0):

My mistake i didn't initiate a function.

```
function insert_terms() {
  $terms = array('Audio','CD','Download','DVD','Publication','Website');
  foreach( $terms as $term ) {
       //intert the term
       wp_insert_term(
            $term, // the term 
            'media-type' // the taxonomy
        );
  }
}

add_action( 'init', 'insert_terms' );
```